# How to count occurrence of specific characters in file using awk command using associative array

Tags: awk, associative-array

I have file like :

```
manish@yahoo.com
Rajesh.patel@hotmail.in
jkl@gmail.uk
New123@utu.ac.in
qwe@gmail.co.in
```

And i want to count occurrence of each domain as

```
Domain Name No of Email
-----------------------
com         1
in          3
uk          1
```

Comment: Do these persons approve of your posting their addresses here in the clear?

Comment: @tripleee: While they _look_ like real email addresses, it appears they aren't (at least according to http://verify-email.org/).

Comment: I would not trust that tool. All it reveals is that they disabled this common spammer technique on their servers.

Comment: Indeed, it tells me my own email address is "Bad".

Comment: @tripleee: Thanks for clarifying that; the tool actually does tell you when the server _refused_ to answer (which I didn't notice initially):  `Requested action not taken`. So, yes, some of the addresses _could_ be real.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sed`, `sort`, `uniq`:

```
sed 's/.*[.]//' input | sort | uniq -c
```

*Gives:*

```
  1 com
  3 in
  1 uk
```

And some make-up with `awk`:

```
sed 's/.*[.]//' input | sort | uniq -c | \
     awk 'BEGIN{print "Domain Name No of Email\n-----------------------"} \
          {print $2"\t\t"$1}'
```

*To get:*

```
Domain Name No of Email
-----------------------
com     1
in      3
uk      1
```

Comment: I originally commented "+1 for an elegant combination of multiple tools", but the comment disappeared; in case it was deleted on purpose: I wanted to point out that this answer is in the spirit of Unix in combining small, special-purpose utilities to achieve a larger task, and as such is an interesting alternative to the monolithic `awk` solution in my own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a pure POSIX `awk` solution (with `sort` invoked from inside the `awk` program):

```
awk -F. -v OFS='\t' '
    # Build an associative array that maps each unique top-level domain
    # (taken from the last `.`-separated field, `$NF`) to how often it
    # occurs in the input.
  { a[$NF]++ }

  END { 
      # Print the header.
    print "Domain Name", "No of Email"
    print "----------------------------"
     # Output the associative array and sort it (by top-level domain).
    for (k in a) print k, a[k] | "sort"
  }
' file
```

---

If you have `GNU awk 4.0` or higher, you can make do without the external `sort` and even easily control the sort field from inside the `gawk` program:

```
gawk -F. -v OFS='\t' '
    # Build an associative array that maps each unique top-level domain
    # (taken from the last `.`-separated field, `$NF`) to how often it
    # occurs in the input.
  { a[$NF]++ }

  END { 
      # Print the header.
    print "Domain Name", "No of Email"
    print "----------------------------"
     # Output the associative array and sort it (by top-level domain).
     # First, control output sorting by setting the order in which 
     # the associative array will be looped over by, via the special
     # PROCINFO["sorted_in"] variable; e.g.:
     #  - Sort by top-level domain, ascending:  "@ind_str_asc"
     #  - Sort by occurrence count, descending: "@val_num_desc"
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"
    for (k in a) print k, a[k]
  }
' file
```